# Value of variable outside a loop in unix

Tags: bash, unix

Please i have tried many options but i dont know how to use the value outside a loop,

```
c='0'   
find $file -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.R' -print0 | while read -d '' file; do

    c=$(($c + $(wc -l < $file) )) 

done 
echo $c
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because pipe creates and processes your while loop in a sub shell. All the changes made in sub shell are not reflected in parent shell.

Use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to avoid forking a sub shell:

```
while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    c=$(($c + $(wc -l < "$file") )) 
done < <(find "$file" -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.R' -print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't have too many files,

```
find "$file" -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.R' -print0 |
xargs -r0 wc -l | tail -n 1
```

or just as well

```
wc -l "$file"/*.[Rr] | tail -n 1
```

will print the total.

```
find "$file" -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.R' -exec wc -l {} \;|
awk '{ c += $1 } END { print c }'
```

works for arbitrarily large collections of files.

(If your `find` supports `-exec` with `+` then by all means use that.)